# PWA studio YARN RUN WATCH: Getting error with invalid json

Tags: pwa-studio, magento2.4.3.p1

i am just trying to setup PWA studio at my local server and i am getting bellow error while run below command yarn run watch

yarn run watch
yarn run v1.22.19
$ webpack-dev-server --progress --color --env.mode development
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://venia-develop-ccewfjy-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/graphql reason: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
at /var/www/html/PWA/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:273:32
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async module.exports (/var/www/html/PWA/pwa-studio-fundamentals/webpack.config.js:62:29) {
type: 'invalid-json'
}
FetchError: invalid json response body at https://venia-develop-ccewfjy-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/graphql reason: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
at /var/www/html/PWA/pwa-studio-fundamentals/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:273:32
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async module.exports (/var/www/html/PWA/pwa-studio-fundamentals/webpack.config.js:62:29)

Could anyone help me to sortout this issue.

Comment: Same for me. Didnt find the answer. Im checking the docs and there should be a packages/.env file with config but maybe it's just after you install venia

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You should connect the backend with the right magento2 installation.
The backend url is inside the file .env in the root directory of the pwa project.

under MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL